# Identify nested location of a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

On my page, I  have a couple instances of the same component:

```
<v-date-picker 
  @click:date="myMethod"
></v-date-picker>
```

```
new Vue({

  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),

  methods: {
    myMethod: function (value) {

      // Get nested components
      // i.e. ['v-app', 'v-content', 'v-sidebar', 'v-date-picker']

    },

...
```

What I'd like to be able to do is identify which date picker is being interacted with. For example, I have one embedded on the page, and I have another in a sidebar.

I'm hoping I can basically do this in a way that doesn't require code in every component -- is there a way to iterate through the global Vue object to get the data I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `event.currentTarget` to return the element that you interacted with:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    doStuff() {
      console.clear()
      console.log(event.currentTarget)
    }
  } 
})
```

```css
div div {border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 4px; margin: 5px; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div @click="doStuff()">Hellooo</div>
  <div @click="doStuff()">Goodbyeee</div>
</div>
```

> **OR**

You can use the [`ref`](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-refs-to-access-your-application-dom-in-vue-js/) attribute and access the elements in the `this.$refs` object:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    doStuff() {
      console.clear()
      console.log(this.$refs)
    }
  } 
})
```

```css
div div {border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 4px; margin: 5px; cursor: pointer; display: inline-block}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div @click="doStuff()" ref="div1">Hellooo</div>
  <div @click="doStuff()" ref="div2">Goodbyeee</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that the event parameter is passed by default so you can just use @click="doStuff()" without a parameter, then use event.currentTarget to get the target.

Comment: @WillC that's pretty cool, I didn't even know that. Thanks man!